# how to generate a random key for AES for python py3rijndael module

Tags: python, cryptography, aes

```
import unittest
import base64
from py3rijndael import Rijndael

def test_rijndael():
    key = 'qBS8uRhEIBsr8jr8vuY9uUpGFefYRL2HSTtrKhaI1tk='
    print(len(key))
    
    a=input("Please Enter Plain text: ")
    plain_text=a.encode('utf-8')
    rijndael = Rijndael(base64.b64decode(key), block_size=32)
    padded_text = plain_text.ljust(32, b'\x1b')
    cipher = rijndael.encrypt(padded_text)
    cipher_text = base64.b64encode(cipher)
    pl_txt=rijndael.decrypt(cipher)
    pl_txt[:len(plain_text)]
    return cipher_text
```

In the above code, I want to generate a random key for the secure private key
changing any character in the key for ex: making
key = 'qBS8uRhEIBsr8jr8vuY9uUpGFefYRL2HSTtrKhaI1tk+' or some thing else, making test to fail with invalid key size. could someone please help with this.
[image: Error info]

Comment: You are using a Base64 encoded key. If you change the `=` to a `+` this corresponds to a 33 bytes key which is not defined for Rijndael causing the error, see [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). One possibility is [`os.urandom(size)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom), which directly returns _size_ random bytes (i.e. Base64 decoding is not necessary).

Comment: Btw, `plain_text.ljust(32, b'\x1b')` is supposed to mimic a [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) padding and implicitly assumes a plaintext of 5 characters because of `b'\x1b'`, s. [test_rijndael.py](https://github.com/meyt/py3rijndael/blob/master/py3rijndael/tests/test_rijndael.py).